# Observable create emit after when user.id is defined

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I am not able to emit user id when it is defined. This is what i know once you subscribe to observable it will listen for changes and emit. Is there any operator which can emit when user id is defined.

I have tried with of and new Observable operators too, I am getting same output.

```
  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.user.id = 1
      ,5000})
   }


   getUserIdChat(): Observable<any> {
      return Observable.create(data=> {
        console.log(" i called")
        if(typeof this.user.id != 'undefined') {
          console.log('next called')
          data.next(this.user.id);
          data.complete();
        }
      })
    }
```

```
constructor(private user: UserService) {
    this.user.getUserIdChat().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data from user', data)
    })
   }
```

i should get output 1 in console

Comment: Usually, you should get along without calling `Observable.create`. If you want to have  one-time emit, use `of(1)`, but if you want to "emit changes" a subject is the way to go - as you can see in the answer of Nosheep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a subject.

```
userSubject = new Subject<number>();

 constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.user.id = 1;
      this.userSubject.next(this.user.id)
      ,5000})
   }

   getUserIdChat(): Observable<any> {
      return userSubject.asObservable()
    }


constructor(private user: UserService) {
    this.user.getUserIdChat().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data from user', data)
    })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

use global subject like this ...

```
_userSubject = new Subject<any>();
constructor() {
        setTimeout(() => {
                this.user.id = 1;
                this._userSubject.next(this.user.id);
                this._userSubject.complete();
            },
            5000);



    getUserIdChat(): Observable<any> {
        return this._userSubject;
    }
}
```